# undefined local variable or method `summitted_password' Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm reading Ruby on Rails tutorial. On chapter 9 after wrote all the code, for sign in and remember me code. My rspec test still fail. this are the exactly error:

```
Failures:
  1) SessionsController POST 'create' with valid email and password should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     undefined local variable or method `summitted_password' for #<Class:0x007fc05395e280>
     # ./app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticate'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController POST 'create' with valid email and password should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     undefined local variable or method `summitted_password' for #<Class:0x007fc05395e280>
     # ./app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticate'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.90025 seconds
7 examples, 2 failures
```

Does anybody have the same problem, because I didn't find any typo.

This is my session_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
     if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

After fixed the type on the user model, I get this error on the test:

```
Failures:
  1) SessionsController POST 'create' with valid email and password should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     undefined method `user_url' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc347354e38>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController POST 'create' with valid email and password should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     undefined method `user_url' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc34679aa20>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.58335 seconds
```

This is my bundle exec rake routes

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method SampleApp::Application#task called at /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
       users POST   /users(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
   new_users GET    /users/new(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
  edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
       users GET    /users(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
       users PUT    /users(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
       users DELETE /users(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
    sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
new_sessions GET    /sessions/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
    sessions DELETE /sessions(.:format)     {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
      signup        /signup(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
      signin        /signin(.:format)       {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
     signout        /signout(.:format)      {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
     contact        /contact(.:format)      {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
       about        /about(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
        help        /help(.:format)         {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
        root        /(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
```

routes.rb file

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :users
  resource :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'

  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'

  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Should it have been `submitted_password`? I think you may have made a typo in `user.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You are a letter out.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code%3aauthenticate_with_salt)

it should be `submitted_password` not `summitted_password` on line 38 of user.rb

Comment: @Jean Please post your SessionsController.  Edit it into the original question instead of into this comment please.

Comment: Looks like that didn't quite help.  The rogue line is redirect_to user, but your code doesn't indicate why.  It may be a routing issue...please post the contents of `bundle exec rake routes`

Comment: this was a new command for me. I just added the text of the bundle exec rake routes

Comment: @Jean Looks like you are missing a route for a single user.  Please post the contents of your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Change `resource :users` to `resources :users`